# Derive type hint for my_dict.items() for return type of function (Python)

Tags: python, mypy

I have a definition of a frequently used type, `MyModel`. For various reasons, in some models I do not work on `MyModel` directly but on a stream of tuples of `key` and `value`. Currently I have to duplicate the type hints for these iterables.

To give a brief example:

```py
import typing as t

MyModel = dict[str, int]


def print_mappings(stream: t.Iterable[tuple[str, int]]) -> None:
   ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_model = {str(n): n for n in range(10)}
    print_mappings(my_model.items())
```

I would like to put something instead of `t.Iterable[...]` that automatically resolves to the return type of `MyModel.items`. Is there a way how this can be achieved?

Comment: I think the only thing you can do currently is define a type alias along side `MyModel`, then use that for `stream`. Then, at least, if the type of `MyModel` changes, the definition of the alias is right there to synchronize with `MyModel`.

Comment: `MyModelItems: TypeAlias = Iterable[tuple[str, int]]`. I'm not aware of any way you can define a tuple consisting of `str` and `int` to use in both definitions. (The obvious attempt like `KV = tuple[str, int]; MyModel = dict[*KV]` doesn't work due to how type-level tuple unpacking is implemented at this time.)

Comment: Using an alias seems to be a good improvement. Thank you for the suggestion.